# Do we have the database access layer to easily switch to other databases in Scala

Tags: sql, database, scala, nosql, data-access-layer

**Requirement:**

I am developing an IoT related application using Scala. In this application, I have to implement the list of APIs for multiple modules. For Example, I 'll take the User module. In the world, most of the applications have the User module. So I am planning to implement a User module and reuse it in other applications.

In the current project, I am going to use Redis database. In future, I may use any SQL/NoSQL databases. So how do I write a single code that can be supported for the other database?

Is this possible to do this in Scala? Kindly provide your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's possible however as far as I am aware there is no good solution to switch between a NoSQL and SQL database easily. If you decide to stick to a SQL DB, the easiest solution would be to use something like [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/), to abstract away the interaction, handling and connection to the DB. This will also you to switch from a SQL DB like MySQL to Postgres fairly easily, eg. by simply re-configuring JOOQ for Postgres.

If you still interested in switching between a NoSQL and a SQL DB, then the best would be to build your own abstraction layer on top of JOOQ, eg. [as done here](http://aakashjapi.com/caching-with-jooq-and-redis/).

By the way, there are SBT plugins for JOOQ (eg. [SBT-JOOQ](https://github.com/kxbmap/sbt-jooq)) and I would recommend using JOOQ together with [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) if you are using a SQL DB.